# c# - How to create Generic T from objectName?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, system.reflection

I have created a `FetchData` method which returns `IList<object>` and it takes `objectName(string)` as parameter(name of the object of which we want to return List).

```
Task<IList<object>> FetchData(string processGuiId, string objectName);
```

I am calling a Gateway method from `FetchData(string processGuiId, string objectName)` to get data from source.

```
_gateway.ReadByQueryAsync<T>();
```

How can I get `T` from `objectName` for `ReadByQueryAsync` method?

Comment: Can you add some code please?

Comment: `typeof(T).Name`? The other way around isn't possible, if I understand correclty.

Comment: You can't. `T` is specified at compile time, whereas `objectName` is provided at runtime. Is there a reason that you need to use a string for the type name?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I am getting objectName as one of the parameter in the API and that is calling FetchData method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "create Generic T from objectName" but you can construct generic method from type.

I think you are looking for [`MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod?view=netcore-3.1) usage would be like this:

```
// somehow get fully qualified name from objectName
vat type = Type.GetType("fully qualified name"); 
var mi = _gateway.GetType().GetMethod("ReadByQueryAsync").MakeGenericMethod(type);
```

And call, for example:

```
mi.Invoke(_gateway, null)
```

or build a lambda with [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) and cache it.

Example with `Enumerable.First()`:

```
var mi = typeof(Enumerable)
    // cause multiple "First" methods
    .GetMethods()
    .Where(mi => mi.Name == "First" && mi.GetParameters().Length == 1)
    .First();
var type = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
var constructed = mi.MakeGenericMethod(type);
var obj = new[] { 1, 2 };
// you will have another order of parameters in Invoke if ReadByQueryAsync is instance method
var x = constructed.Invoke(
    null, // null cause First is extension method, should be obj if instance
    new[] { obj } // should be null for parameterless instance method
    ); // x = 1
```

Comment: I will try this